# Adding property from v-for into dynamic :style in vuejs

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, vue.js

I have this structure:

```
<div v-for="item in principal" class="cardgrande cardeffects imagehover">
  <div v-bind:style='{ background: "linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(0,0,0,.6),rgba(0,0,0,.2) 40%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,.4)), url(" + item.midia + ")", }' class="flexcolumn card">
    <div class="texto">{{item.titulo}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This item.midia doesn't enter into my dynamic style. I need to get this because it is the url of my image (got from v-for).

Comment: Can you post a sample of what an item or principal looks like?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the curly braces here. Just add your dynamic attribute of the form:

```
<tag :attribute="'selector:' + yourVariable" />
```

Also use [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) instead of `background` to set multiple background images. In your case that would be:

```
<div v-for="item in principal" class="cardgrande cardeffects imagehover">
  <div :style="'background-image: linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(0,0,0,.6),rgba(0,0,0,.2) 40%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,.4)), url(' + item.midia + ')" class="flexcolumn card">
  <div class="texto">{{item.titulo}}</div>
</div>
```

See [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a method that returns styles

```
  <div v-for="item in principal" class="cardgrande cardeffects imagehover">
    <div :style="itemStyle(item)" class="flexcolumn card">
      <div class="texto">{{item.titulo}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Add below method

```
  itemStyle(item) {
    return { background: `linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(0,0,0,.6),rgba(0,0,0,.2) 40%,rgba(0,0,0,.2) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,.4)), url(${item.midia})` }
  }
```